# How to insert a value that contains percentage symbols?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a query like as below

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, ...)
VALUES ('a.jsp?action=delete&TASK_ID=%TASK_ID%', ...);
```

On executing it in SQLdeveloper, it's asking to enter the value of TASK_ID. How do I skip it and just enter it as a part of the value?

Comment: A q literal perhaps?

Comment: Sorry, I am a novice in database/SQL? What's a q literal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the percentage sign, but ampersand. It says that you want to use a **substitution variable** (but you don't).

What to do? Prior to executing that `insert`, type `set define off` and execute it. Then run `insert`.

Comment: I'm an Oracle beginner. Can a q literal be used instead? How would you write it?

Comment: do what littlefoot said, add 'set scan off' in front of your INSERT, then run both together with F5

Comment: @jarlh, we use the q-quoting mechanism when we deal with a string that contains single quotes. If you have to enclose it into another pair of single quotes, things go *wild* so you have to "escape" them and can easily get lost. In this case, problem is another character - & - and q-quoting mechanism wouldn't help with that.